# How to visit and set values to an array using the each() of jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a array obj in JQuery and I will like to visit it and set values on it using the `.each()` function of JQuery. But I still got a lot of errors when I am traying to do this, maybe I think, I do something wrong. This my array:

```
var person_time_array = {time: " ", person: " "};
```

And this is what I am trying to do: Visit it and check it if a person is already inside, if not then I introduce the new value (person and time), if the person is already inside I just update his time. In the end i just show a alert to check if everything is correct

```
jQuery.each(person_time_array,function(i,val){
            if(val != current_person){
               person_time_array.person = current_person;
               person_time_array.time = time_result;
            }
            else
               person_time_array.time = time_result;
            alert(val);
});
```

But I still got mistakes, like all values are inside, the code doesn't update nothing :(
Can Please somebody help me? THX!

Comment: Has the answers below solved your problem? If so, you can mark any one answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
var person_time_array = [{
  time: '1',
  person: 'name1'
}, {
  time: '2',
  person: 'name2'
}];

// Check for person by name 'Tim'.
var found = false;
var current_person = "name1";
var time_result = 10;
jQuery.each(person_time_array, function(i, personObj) {
  if (personObj.person === current_person) {
    personObj.time = time_result;
    found = true;
    return false;
  }

});
if (!found) {
  var obj = {};

  obj.person = current_person;
  obj.time = time_result;
  person_time_array.push(obj);
}
console.log(person_time_array)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Might be worth adding that the current_person has to be a string, like "Name1" above, not an object.

Comment: Updated answer. Please check

Comment: nice i will remove my comment :D

Comment: Hi @SandeepNayak cool, Thx!! this was great! I was forgeting a lot of logical points like a found flag and the === from JS :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var person_time_array = []; // this is an array 
var exists = false;

var current_person = "PersonTest";
var time_result    = "1"; 

jQuery.each(person_time_array,function(i,val)
{
    if(val.person == current_person)
         exists = i;
});

if(typeof exists === 'number')
   person_time_array[exists].time = time_result ;
else
   person_time_array.push({person: current_person,time :time_result});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
person_time_array.forEach(function(val, index) {
     if(val.person != current_person){
               person_time_array[index].person = current_person;
               person_time_array[index].time = time_result;
     }
    else
        person_time_array[index].time = time_result;
});
```